# How do I deconstruct and display res from strapi api with usestate?

Tags: next.js

Im trying to display the titles, price, description and allergies from the strapi Api:http://localhost:1337/api/pizzasarpsborgs.

[api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD9RE.png)

Not really sure how to deconstruct the res. Can someone help?

This is my current code:

````
export default function Menu() {
  const [pizzasarpsborgs, setPizzas] = useState(['']);

  async function fetchPizza() {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/pizzasarpsborgs');
    const data = await res.json();
    setPizzas(data.data);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPizza();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {pizzasarpsborgs.map((pizza) => (
        <p key={pizza.id}>{pizza.id}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Comment: What issue/error are you seeing?

Comment: With the current code it displays the id, but its the ID outside the array og objects. So with the current code I'm getting the Id and no error, I have tried everything and It seems like I dont understand how to deconstruct the api correctly.

Answer (score 0):

can you try the following and let me know if it works.

```
{pizzasarpsborgs.length ? pizzasarpsborgs.map((pizza) => (
    <div key={pizza.id}>
        <h1>{pizza.attributes.title}</h1>
        <p>{pizza.attributes.price}</p>
        <p>{pizza.attributes.description}</p>
        <p>{pizza.attributes.allergies}</p>
    </div>
)) : null}
```

I don't have the development environment setup as of now, so I am writing this off the top of my head. So please let me know if any errors pop up.

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply. Getting an error on this.

```Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')

Source
pages/restaurants/menuvikane.js (25:32) @ eval

  23 | {pizzasarpsborgs.map((pizza) => (
  24 |   <div key={pizza.id}>
> 25 |     <h1>{pizza.attributes.title}</h1>
     |                          ^
  26 |     <p>{pizza.attributes.price}</p>
  27 |     <p>{pizza.attributes.description}</p>
  28 |     <p>{pizza.attributes.allergies}</p>
Call Stack
Menu
pages/restaurants/menuvikane.js (23:23)
Show collapsed frames```

Comment: Aaah yes, I will update my answer. Please check again.

Comment: Also remove the quotes from the useState as well. const [pizzasarpsborgs, setPizzas] = useState([]);

Comment: ``` return (
    {pizzasarpsborgs.length ? pizzasarpsborgs.map((pizza) => (
        <div key={pizza.id}>
            <h1>{pizza.attributes.title}</h1>
            <p>{pizza.attributes.price}</p>
            <p>{pizza.attributes.description}</p>
            <p>{pizza.attributes.allergies}</p>
        </div>
    )) : null}
  );```

Does not work either, getting two errors: 1. Parsing Error: Unexpected token, epeted ",".

Comment: What is the other error?